visibilitychange not firing on browser close in firefox
I am trying to send some data for analytics on browser close and the visibilitychange event listener is not being triggered on browser close on firefox. This works as expected in chrome.
MDN says this event fires on browser close.
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
  if(document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    navigator.sendBeacon('http://localhost:3001')
  }
})


what if you use beforeunload? Note: how can you be sure the event doesn't trigger - perhaps the issue is that document.visibilityState hasn't changed to hidden when you close Firefox - to test, remove the if condition - again, this is just to test if the event fires or not

your edit: MDN says this event fires on browser close. - but it doesn't say if document.visibility is changed to hidden - why would it? the document is closed, not hidden i.e. The page content is not visible to the user. In practice this means that the document is either a background tab or part of a minimized window, or the OS screen lock is active - no mention of "or the browser has been closed" :p

visibilitychange works fine in Firefox (version 56+), there has to be something else going on in your code.

@JaromandaX "fires with a visibilityState of hidden when a user navigates to a new page, switches tabs, closes the tab, minimizes or closes the browser".

@Teemu - yes - but I refer you to the documentation for document.visibilityState - which has nothing to do with, nor makes ANY mention of visibilitychange EVENT

I have tried testing it after removing the check for document.visibilityState as well. Still does not seem to fire for me.  @JaromandaX

@Teemu. The event and the request is firing reliably on tab close, tab switch, locking the screen and switching apps etc. It doesn't seem only in this particular case.

I've just tried in Firefox ... fires when visibility changes, fires when the TAB is closed ... does NOT fire when browser is closed - so, yeah, seems to be a bug in firefox

I'm using visibilitychange event as a part of logging system in a quite similar way you've used it, and it has been working fine for years, also in FF. I've a fallback for older browsers, though, I've to check whether FF uses it in the browser-close case (unfortunately that will take several hours).

@Teemu - and it fires when you close the browser? Not the tab, the browser? Because it doesn't in Windows at least

@JaromandaX does it work for you if you paste the code block in the browser's console? It not working for me in this case as well.

@prajotsurey - your code never works, even removing the if, the sendbeacon never fires when the browser is closed ... have you considered beforeunload yet?

@JaromandaX I have tried using beforeunload but discarded it as it does not fire reliably on mobile and the visibilitychange method is recommended over it as per MDN

but you can do both :p at least while firefox is being buggy :p

actually, there's no way to tell if the visibilitychange event fires or not - all I can confirm is the sendBeacon does not happen

@JaromandaX Interestingly, the request is fired when I have two windows open and close one of them. Only when the last remaining window is closed, the request is not fired. Same happens if I replace the request with window.open().
And for beforeUnload, looks like I'll have to go with it for the time being.

the request is fired when I have two windows open and close one of them. so, that would be when you close a TAB?
